# Drop down list validation on submit using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I have five drop down lists with the same options in my form and there should be validation that a drop down cannot have the value which already selected from previous drop down...

```
<select id ="selected" name="expenseType" class="dynamic_select" >
     <option value="0">-select-</option>
     <option value="1">Van</option>
     <option value="2">SUV</option>
     <option value="3">Hatcback</option>
     <option value="4">Jeep</option>
</select>
```

On submitting, how can I validate this? I am using the jQuery validation plugin to validate the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
var isValid = true;
var $dynamicSelect = $("select.dynamic_select");
$dynamicSelect.each(function(){
   if($dynamicSelect.find("option[value="+this.value+"]:selected").length > 1){
      isValid = false;
      return false;
   }
});
```

Now use `isValid` variable to show the appropriate error message or go ahead and submit the form.

Comment: it should consider only the selected drop down list... i mean to say is it should not consider the drop down which is showing -Select_ option

Answer (score 1):

Here is some script that uses the jQuery validator framework to do what I think you're after.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.validator.addMethod('uniqueselection', function (v, e, d) {
            if (v == '-select-') {
                return true;
            }
            if ($(".dynamic_select option[value='" + v + "']:selected").size() > 1) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });

        $('select').each(function () {
            $(this).rules('add', { uniqueselection: 'This can be selected once' });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are this will alert if two select are same value, just use five instead of two acording to your needs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#target').bind('submit', function(){
                if($('#selected1').val() == $('#selected2').val()){
                    alert($('#selected1').val()+" "+ $('#selected2').val());
                }
           }); 
        });
    </script>



 <form method="post" id="target">
 <select id ="selected1" name="expenseType" class="dynamic_select" >
     <option value="0">-select-</option>
     <option value="1">Van</option>
     <option value="2">SUV</option>
     <option value="3">Hatcback</option>
     <option value="4">Jeep</option>
 </select> 
  <select id ="selected2" name="expenseType" class="dynamic_select" >
     <option value="0">-select-</option>
     <option value="1">Van</option>
     <option value="2">SUV</option>
     <option value="3">Hatcback</option>
     <option value="4">Jeep</option>
 </select> 
 <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```